# How to find the constants $a$ and $b$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, hamiltonian

We consider the motion of a particle without spin submitted by the hamiltonian $H$ defined by the eigen-value equation:$H|n_1,n_2\rangle =(n_1^2+n_2^2)|n_1,n_2\rangle $
 the proper kets of $H$ verify the orthonormalization relation. At the initial moment, the particle is in the normed state $ |\psi(0)\rangle$ at the unit such that $|\psi(0)\rangle =a|1,1\rangle+b|1,2\rangle$, where $a$ and $b$ are real positive constants.
Find $a$ and $b$ knowing that the energy at the initial moment is $3$.

This is what I tried:
$$H|\psi(0)\rangle=E(a|1,1\rangle+b|1,2\rangle)$$
$$H|1,1\rangle=2|1,1\rangle,\ H|1,2\rangle=5|1,2\rangle,$$ but then what I have to do to find $a$ and $b$?

Comment: -1 for a undescriptive subject.

Answer (score 1):

The equations you write are correct, now use the fact that the initial energy is 3, i.e. $\langle \psi(0)|H|\psi(0)\rangle = 3$ and that your state is normalized, i.e. $\langle \psi(0)|\psi(0)\rangle = 1$. This gives you a system of two linear equations for $|a|^2$ and $|b|^2$ from which you can determine a and b up to some phase factors.

Comment: Is the one of the equation $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$?,I didn't find the second equation because I don't have H

Comment: Yes, this comes from the normalization. What do you mean you do not have H? Can you express $\langle \psi(0)|H|\psi(0)\rangle$ via a and b?

Comment: I have $<\psi(0)|H|\psi(0)>=<\psi(0)|H\psi(0)>=2a^2+5b^2$ after determination,is it right?

Comment: Right, plus you know that this equals 3, there you go.

Comment: I have found $a=\sqrt{2/3}$,$b=1/\sqrt{3}$

Comment: I have a new question:how to find the state $|\psi(t)>$ of the particle at the moment t>0?

Comment: This is done via the time evolution operator, but since this is another question we should not mix everything together here.

Answer (score 0):

This equation 
$$H|\psi(0)\rangle=E(a|1,1\rangle+b|1,2\rangle)$$
is not correct. The energy is not the same for both states, so you can't factor it out.

Comment: In the sparse context given by OP, E is the eigenvalue that belongs to $|\psi(0)\rangle$. Why should that not be allowed?

Comment: It would be more correct to denote it $E_1 a|1,1\rangle+E_2 b|1,2\rangle)$

Comment: @Formelverleger OP's question isn't very clear, but I'm pretty sure the question intends $E$ to be the expectation value of the energy in the state $|\psi(t=0)\rangle$ not the energy eigenvalue. (In fact, it can't be an eigenvector as its a sum of non-degenerate eigenvectors.)

Comment: That may be the intention, but as it was written, the equation is still wrong.